# Expands background on a circle shape

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a circle that expands-change color from the center, and i want it to expand it with border-radius: 50%, you'll understand what i'm talking about if you watch the example i made

> [Checkout the sample i made for better understanding](http://angel.hayling.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/#detail-title)

### *Thanks for any help*

Comment: in back ground-image use circle image instead of gradient is very easy to achieve your required animation .... i hope it works for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the quote blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a `transition` over an inset `box-shadow`, like so

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  color: #FFF;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #03BF60;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow .75s 0s, color .5s 0s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #DCEDC8;
}

div p { 
  color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  color: #444;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 150px #DCEDC8;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
     Responsive design. I get this certificate by 
     learning HTML, CSS, web design, media query plus 
     animations using keyframes, declaring variables 
     on css and a lot of CSS components.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to use Keyframes...

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="to-animate animate"></div>
</div>

.shape {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.to-animate {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.animate {
  animation: my-animation 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  to {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hernangiraldo89/ba3ne675/

Keyframes are a powerful tool, here its documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes